Firebase Deploying Issue
I am trying to deploy my react project to firebase, but there's an issue occuring while build.
When i build the project and running on localhost: ..., its working, but after build, when i try to  deploying it in firebase, it's not working.
when i inspect the deployed URL [ inspect-> Application-> Javascript-> main.9a3826cc.js ], main.9a3826cc.js is empty.
     *The main.9a3826cc.js is not empty while running on localhost* 

How can i solve this?
